# Get appWidgetId in RemoveViewsFactory?

Tags: android, widget, android-widget, android-appwidget, android-orientation

Is there a way to get the `appWidgetId` for the current widget instance being updated within the `RemoteViewsFactory`? If per-se you invalidated the views for that `appWidgetId` from the Provider class?

I'm trying to provide dynamic layouts for multiple instances of the same widget, but I need to know which widget instance is currently being updated by the `RemoteViewsFactory` to loads the right data in `getViewAt()`